# LinearLayout Weight works wrong

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Hey i created a LinearLayout with 2 RelativeLayout in it. One RelativeLayout has a weight of 8 and the other a weight of 2. When i launch my App the Layout which should use 80% of the Screen takes 20% of the Screen and the other RelativeLayout that should use 20% of the Screen takes 80% of the Screen.

Here my Code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight="8">
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="2">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weights do work perfectly... if you use them correctly. The weighted dimension must have a size of **0dp**. That's it.

Comment: @MBerg What/Where is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using weights on a LinearLayout, you must take care of the `weightSum` value. By default it's 1, and in `layout_weight` you can have float values if you require it. Children should specify `layout_weight` value, and `layout_width` or `layout_height` must be `0dp`, depending on the orientation of the parent.
It's a bit strange you didn't fixed it by yourself, because Android Studio automatically warns you.
Anyway, below you find the fixed layout. Let me know if it works for you.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="8">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I replaced `fill_parent` with `match_parent`, because if you used it, it means you are developing for API Level 8+, so you should use "match_parent" (it has been replaced, but value remains the same "-1").

Comment: `weightSum` is not necessary.

Comment: oh thank you i just fixed the layout_height for the RelativeLayout.